# Rescuing a vertically clipped histogram

Tags: plotting, graphics, histograms

I recently ran a rather time intensive calculation and plotted the results in a histogram by simply called Histogram[data].  However, because of a rather serious error on my part, I recently lost my original data and all I have is the histogram plot.

I need to change the vertical cut-off on the histogram (it will cut off any bars with an event count >= N).  I can hover over the bars and read the values, so I know the information is there, but how can I change the value of N for the vertical cutoff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];
 hh = Histogram[data]
```

[image]

Copy the graphic you have (`Ctrl+C`) and in a new cell type `gr=` and paste your graphic (`Ctrl+V`):

[image]

```
 gr /. RectangleBox[x : {_, _}, y : {y1_, y2_}, z__] :> 
       RectangleBox[x, {y1, Min[y2, 30]}, z]
```

gives

[image]

Update: An alternative approach is to replace the `PlotRange` and `PlotRangePadding` options of `gr`:

```
 gr /. {HoldPattern[PlotRange -> _] :> PlotRange -> {0, 30},
     HoldPattern[PlotRangePadding -> _] :> PlotRangePadding -> 0}
```

[image]

You can also use `Show` with `PlotRange` and `PlotRangePadding` options:

```
 Show[gr, PlotRange -> {0, 30}, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

which gives an output identical to the last one.

Comment: I recieve an error saying the FrontEnd 'If is not a graphics primitive or directive.

Comment: I cannot regenerate the histogram, I only have the graphic.

Comment: @Nikki,  I updated with the answer showing how to use the graphic you have. Regarding the error message in your first comment, I am not getting any error messages (using Windows Vista 64bit, Mathematica Version 9).

Comment: That's effectively what I tried earlier... hmm... does it still work for you if you quit the kernel and then try it?

Comment: Yes, it does work with a fresh kernel. Just checked that it also works in Version 8.0.4.0. Do you get the same error message when you use the methods on a new histogram? If not, perhaps you can post the `FullForm` of your graphic to see if there is anything specific that is causing the issue. (To get the `FullForm` of your graphic, just copy-paste it inside the brackets in `FullForm[]` in a new cell.)

Comment: It works!  However, I can't seem to suppress the error and it turns the background pink.  Can I get it to display normally anyway?